# Can I mock another method in then statement of first method?

Tags: java, scala, mockito

Can I mock another method in `then` statement of mocked method ?

I'm mocking `ResultSet.getByte()` for 2 different arguments

```
when(rs.getByte("present")).thenReturn(5)
when(rs.getByte("missing")).thenReturn(0)
```

What I also want to have is that mocked `getByte` not only returns value but also mock `ResultSet.wasNull` to return once `false` in first case and `true` in another one.

Here is how I run scenario

```
val rs: WrappedResultSet = ...
val res3: Option[Byte] = rs.byteOpt("present")
val res4: Option[Byte] = rs.byteOpt("missing")
res3.isDefined should be(true)
res4.isDefined should be(false)
```

Implementation of `byteOpt`getter internally calls `wasNull` right after `getByte`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do something like that:

```
final ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(rs.getByte(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Long>() {
   @Override
   public Long answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
       String argument = (String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
       Long answer;
       if("present".equals(argument)){
          when(rs.wasNull()).thenReturn(false); //mock to return false, when present was argument
          answer = 5L;
       else {
          when(rs.wasNull()).thenReturn(true); //mock to return true, when something else was sent to method
          answer = 0L;
       }
       return answer;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem is not the fact that I have to support two arguments. I can't figure out if I can conditionally mock other method BEFORE first mock is executed :)

Comment: Uh, ok :P Sorry then. I though you want to mock it after execution, that's why mocking inside answer in if block. After your line with:    "What I also want to have is that mocked getByte not only returns value but also mock ResultSet.wasNull to return once false in first case and true in another one."

Answer (score 0):

And what would be wrong with:

```
when(rs.getByte("present")).thenReturn(5);
when(rs.wasNull()).thenReturn(false);
```

?

Comment: Question is updated. I have 20 getters similar to `byteOpt`. I'll have to mock these methods twice per each getter. I wanted to avoid that,

Comment: Then your problem is of a different nature: your production code does to many things. If you need so much mocking; I would suggest to step back; and either rework your design on your own; or at least give more information in your question.